# Average over value for distinct ids with many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I have these two tables:

Events

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

Many to many

| EventID | Values3 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 7 |

and two lists:

```
Values2List = [1,3]
Values3List = [0,2,3,4,7,8]
```

I need to get the Average value of Value1 for all Events where Value2 is in Values2List and ANY of the corresponding Values3 are in the Values3List.
However I do NOT want to double count Events that have multiple matching Value3's

I am thinking something like:

```
SELECT AVG(e.Value1)
FROM Events e
JOIN ManyToMany m
ON e.ID = m.EventID
WHERE e.Value2 in Values2List
AND m.Values3 in Values3List
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fde479/2/0

This would give me the average of all values that pass but it would double count those that have multiple values3's in the list and gives me 1/3 instead of the desired 1/2.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the distinct combinations of `ID` and `value1` from the join and then aggregate:

```
SELECT AVG(value1)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT e.ID, e.value1
  FROM events e JOIN MtoM m
  ON e.ID = m.EventID
  WHERE e.value2 IN (1,3) AND m.value3 IN (0,2,3,4,7,8)
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbdb20f799b46af1422445e7c8c8f6d9).

Answer (score 1):

Might do something like this

```
select avg(e.Value1)
  from events e
 where e.value2 in (1,3)
   and exists
         ( select 1
             from many_to_many mm
            where e.id = mm.event_id
              and mm.value3 in (0,2,3,4,7,8)
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the second table and put the result in the join

```sql
SELECT AVG(e.value1)
FROM Events e
INNER JOIN 
(select distinct t.EventID from MtoM t where t.value3 in (0,2,3,4,7,8))m
ON e.ID = m.EventID
WHERE e.value2 in (1,3)
```